# How to wait for all promises to be resolved before continuing

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have this code

```
     async function concurrent() {
        await Promise.all([
            getColorCount('black'),
            getColorCount('purple'),
            getColorCount('red'),
            getColorCount('amber'),
            getColorCount('yellow'),
            getColorCount('white'),
            buildChartData()
        ]);

    }
    concurrent();
    res.json(chartData); //This is run before above promises are complete
```

My understanding was that async await halted the code until complete, but in this case, res.json(chartData) runs before the above promises have been completed.

How do I ensure that all promises have completed before responding to the client with `res.json(chartData);`?

Comment: `await` waits inside the `async` function, not outside it. It is syntactic sugar for Promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` a value from the function, or use `.then()` within `concurrent()` function call

```
 function concurrent() {
   return Promise.all([
        getColorCount('black'),
        getColorCount('purple'),
        getColorCount('red'),
        getColorCount('amber'),
        getColorCount('yellow'),
        getColorCount('white'),
        buildChartData()
    ]);

  }
  concurrent()
  .then(chartData => 
    res.json(chartData)
  )
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```
 async function concurrent() {
   const promises = await Promise.all([
        getColorCount('black'),
        getColorCount('purple'),
        getColorCount('red'),
        getColorCount('amber'),
        getColorCount('yellow'),
        getColorCount('white'),
        buildChartData()
    ]);
    return promises;
  }
  concurrent()
  .then(chartData => 
    res.json(chartData)
  )
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer because it was the most complete example and included error catching.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
concurrent().then(promiseResult => {
      res.json(chartData);
});
```

An async function always returns a promise and hence using "then", you can ensure the completion of an async function in a synchronised way.

Answer (score 1):

You will need `.then` after promise.all. Then will return an array of values returned from your function calls in order they were initially called.

`Promise.all([
            getColorCount('black'),
            getColorCount('purple'),
            getColorCount('red'),
            getColorCount('amber'),
            getColorCount('yellow'),
            getColorCount('white'),
            buildChartData()
        ])
.then( function( responeses ) { console.log ( responses )};`

And take a look at the responses array, it should all fall into place

Answer (score 1):

`concurrent` is an asynchrounous function, as you indicate with the keyword `async`. That's why `res.json` is executed just after calling concurrent, without waiting.

You can be tempted to use await like this:

```
await concurrent();
res.json(chartData);
```

but it will throw an error because await can't be used outside a async context.

Unluckily you will need the traditional `then` to fulfill the promise:

```
 concurrent().then(() => {
     res.json(chartData);
 });
```

Apart from that, is `buildChartData` asynchronous? Maybe it should be executed outside `Promimse.all`